# Spring could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I am trying to test a change password functionality in my spring application but i got an exception.

I have read similar problems here and tried to use them but they didn't help me. The problem occurs when I want to run the test class to test whether the a **method for changing the password** is working correctly. Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = UiApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SecurityServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    SecurityService securityService;

    @Test
    public void testLoginSuccess() {
        securityService.login("user1", "pass1");
    }

    @Test(expected = BadCredentialsException.class)
    public void testLoginFail() {
        securityService.login("user1", "pass11");
    }
    @Test
    public void testChangePwd(){

        securityService.changePwd("user1", "pass1", "123", "123");
        securityService.login("user1", "123");
    }
}
```

The problem occured when I added the last test - `testChangePwd()`, before adding it was working properly.

UPDATE- the SecurityService is an interface and its implementation is the following class:

```
@Service
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SecurityServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private UserDaoImpl userDao;
    @Override
    public void login(String username, String password) {

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

        if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            logger.info(String.format("Auto login %s successfully!", username));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void changePwd(String username, String password, String newPwd, String againPwd) {
         UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

            authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

            if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
                if(newPwd.equals(againPwd))
                userDao.findByUserName(username).setPassword(password);
            }

    }

}
```

Here is the exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at com.example.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.findByUserName(UserDaoImpl.java:26)
    at com.example.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$94db05c6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.example.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59fce477.findByUserName(<generated>)
    at com.example.auth.impl.SecurityServiceImpl.changePwd(SecurityServiceImpl.java:50)
    at com.example.auth.SecurityServiceTest.testChangePwd(SecurityServiceTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Saying **but i got an exception** is not enough. You need to write down `Exception` details. Also, what is `SecurityService` esp. its' `changePwd` method?

Comment: @SabirKhan I updated the post